# How to implement IDisposable inheritance in a repository?

Tags: c#, repository

I am creating a generic repository and do not know what the correct way to implement the dispose functionality:

I'm not using IoC/DI, but i'll refactor my code in the future to do this, so:

My code:

**IUnitOfWork Interface:**

```
namespace MyApplication.Data.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
   {
       void Save();
   }
}
```

**DatabaseContext class:**

```
namespace MyApplication.Data.Infra
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
    {
        public DatabaseContext(): base("SQLDatabaseConnectionString")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            // Same code.
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        #region Entities mapping
        public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
        // >>> A lot of tables
        #endregion

        public void Save()
        {
            base.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**IGenericRepository interface:**

```
namespace MyApplication.Data.Interfaces
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();

        IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

        T Find(params object[] keys);

        T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

        bool Any(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

        void Insert(T entity);

        void Edit(T entity);

        void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    }
}
```

**GenericRepository class:**

```
namespace MyApplication.Data.Repositories
{
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T> where T  : class
    {
        private DatabaseContext _context;
        private DbSet<T> _entity;

        public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            if (unitOfWork == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("unitofwork");

            _context = unitOfWork as DatabaseContext;
            _entity = _context.Set<T>();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _entity;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _entity.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
        }

        // I delete some of the code to reduce the file size.

        #region Dispose
        public void Dispose()
        {
            // HERE IS MY FIRST DOUBT: MY METHOD ITS OK?!
            // I saw implementations with GC.Suppress... and dispose in destructor, etc.

            _context.Dispose();
        }
       #endregion
    }
}
```

**IUserRepository interface:**

```
namespace MyApplication.Data.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUserRepository : IGenericRepository<User> { }
}
```

**UserRepository class:**

```
namespace MyApplication.Data.Repositories
{
    public class UserRepository : GenericRepository<User>, IUserRepository, IDisposable
    {
        public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork) {}
    }
}
```

**UserController controller class:**

```
namespace MyApplication.Presentation.MVCWeb.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private IProfileRepository _profileRepository;
        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public UserController()
        {
            this._unitOfWork = new DatabaseContext();
            this._userRepository = new UserRepository(_unitOfWork);
            this._profileRepository = new ProfileRepository(_unitOfWork);
        }

        public ActionResult List()
        {
            return View(this._userRepository.GetAll().ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Profiles = new SelectList(this._profileRepository.GetAll().ToList(), "Id", "Name");

            return View(new User());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "Id, Status, CompanyId")] User model)
        {
            ViewBag.Profiles = new SelectList(this._profileRepository.GetAll().ToList(), "Id", "Name");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.EmpresaId = 1;
                model.Status = Status.Active;

                _userRepository.Insert(model);
                _unitOfWork.Save();

                return RedirectToAction("List");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

So, when and how i disposal my controller and/or my repositories and context?

Comment: You're confusing the type with the type parameter.

Answer (score 14):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Example of my controller:

```
private IGenericRepository<Profile> _repository; 
private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new DatabaseContext();
public ProfileController() 
{ 
    this._repository = new GenericRepository<Profile>(_unitOfWork); 
}

public class ProfileController : Controller 
{
    private IGenericRepository<Profile> _repository;
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new DatabaseContext();  
    public ProfileController()  
    { 
        this._repository = new GenericRepository<Profile>(_unitOfWork);  
    }
}
```

With the code that you have now, the best thing to do is to override `Controller.Dispose(bool disposing)` and dispose of the repository in there.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        IDisposable d = _repository as IDisposable;
        if (d != null)
            d.Dispose();
        GC.SupressFinalize(this);
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Once you start using an IOC container, all of this disposal code will go away. Construction and disposal should happen at the container level. The container will be the only place where it is known or cared that the repository and unit of work are disposable.

But I suspect that none of these classes need to be disposable in the first place. You should use SqlConnection in a using block. It does not need to be a class-level field in `DatabaseContext`.

---

Please forgive the length of this answer. I must establish some fundamentals in order for my recommendation to make sense.

**S.O.L.I.D.**

*SOLID ... stands for five basic principles of object-oriented programming and design.* The two principles that are of concern here are the `I` and `S`.

**Interface Segregation Principle (ISP)**

Including `IDisposable` on the `IGenericRepository<T>` interface explicitly violates the ISP.

It does this because a repository's disposability (and the imperative to properly dispose of the object) is unrelated to it's designed purpose, which is to Get and Store aggregate root objects. By combining the interfaces together, you get a non-segregated interface.

Why is this important aside from violating some theoretical principle? I will explain that below. But first I have to cover another of the SOLID principles:

**Single Resposibility Principle**

I always keep this article, [Taking the Single Responsibility Principle Seriously](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/137636/taking-the-single-responsibility-principle-seriously/), handy when I re-factor functional code into good OO code. This is not an easy subject and the article is very dense. But it is invaluable as a thorough explanation of SRP.

Understanding SRP and disregarding the flaws in 99.9% of all MVC controllers out there which take many DI constructor parameters, the one flaw that is pertinent here is:

*Making the controller be responsible for both using the repository and disposing of the repository crosses over to a different level of abstraction*, and this violates the SRP.

Explanation:

So you're calling at least two public methods on the repository object. One to `Get` an object and one to `Dispose` of the repository. There's nothing wrong with that, right? Ordinarily no, there is nothing wrong with calling two methods on the repository or any object.

But `Dispose()` is special. The convention of disposal of an object is that it will no longer be useful after being disposed. This convention is one reason why the *using pattern* establishes a separate code block:

```
using (var foo = new Bar())
{
    ...  // This is the code block
}

foo.DoSomething();  // <- Outside the block, this does not compile
```

This is technically legal:

```
var foo = new Bar();
using (foo)
{
    ...  // This is the code block
}

foo.DoSomething();   // <- Outside the block, this will compile
```

But this gives a warning of usage of an object after it has been disposed. This is not proper which is why you don't see examples of this usage in the MS documentation.

Because of this unique convention, `Dispose()`, is more closely related to constructing and destructing an object than to the usage of other members of an object, even though it is exposed as a simple public method.

Construction and Disposal are on the same low level of abstraction. But because the controller is not constructing the repository itself, it lives on a higher level of abstraction. When disposing the repository, it is reaching outside of its level of abstraction to fiddle with the repository object at a different level. This violates the SRP.

**Code Reality**

Okay, all that theory means exactly what as far as my code is concerned?

Consider what the controller code looks like when it disposes of the repository itself:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    IGenericRepository<Customer> _customerRepo;
    IMapper<Customer, CustomerViewModel> _mapper;

    public CustomerController(
        IMapper<Customer, CustomerViewModel> customerRepository,
        IMapper<Customer, CustomerViewModel> customerMapper)
    {
        _customerRepo = customerRepository;
        _customerMapper = customerMapper;
    }

    public ActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        CustomerViewModel vm;
        using (_customerRepo)  // <- This looks fishy
        {
            Customer cust = _customerRepo.Get(id);
            vm = _customerMapper.MapToViewModel(cust);
        }
        return View(wm);
    }

    public ActionResult Update(CustomerViewModel vm)
    {
        Customer cust = _customerMapper.MapToModel(vm);
        CustomerViewModel updatedVm;
        using(_customerRepo)  // <- Smells like 3 week old flounder, actually
        {
            Customer updatedCustomer = _customerRepo.Store(cust);
            updatedVm = _customerMapper.MapToViewModel(updatedCustomer);
        }
        return View(updatedVm);
    }
}
```

The controller must receive a useful (non disposed) repository when it is constructed. This is a common expectation. But don't call two methods in the controller or it will break. This controller is a one-shot deal only. Plus, you cannot even call one public method from within another. E.g. the `Update` method could call `Get` after storing the model in the repository in order to return an updated Customer View. But this would blow up.

**Conclusion**

Receiving the repository as a parameter means that something else is responsible for creating the repository. That something else should also be responsible for properly disposing of the repository.

The alternative of disposing an object at the same level of abstraction as using its (other) public members, when the lifetime of the object and possible subsequent usage of the object is not under direct control, is a ticking time bomb.

The rule of `IDisposable` is this: *It is never acceptable to inherit `IDisposable` in a another functional interface declaration because `IDisposable` is never a functional concern, but an implementation detail only.*

Comment: Nice, but my point still stands. I don't like constructor injection, either. It could be that I'm not doing Web stuff, though. Maybe in an ASP.Net MVC scenario this would make more sense, but it does not in my configurable single-tier-or-multi-tier Client/Server application framework. My services get a reference to the Repo by doing `using (var repo = TypeResolver.Get<IRepository>())` so I don't care about SRP or whatever, that makes my code cleaner.

Comment: @HighCore That assumes that your locator provides a new Repository. Anyways, the OP is about injected objects, not located ones.

Comment: @HighCore BTW, this isn't about contradicting your point or disproving it.

Comment: in that case, +1 for an excellent, well documented, detailed answer.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks. The OP began actively arguing against the validity of my recommendation. It is important for future readers to know that there are valid alternatives.

Comment: Keith, first of all, thank you for your answer. I understood what you said, but, not all, example: You said that my controller should not worry about the dispose of my repository, so, instead of use _repo.dispose(true), i should use the using(_repo){} statement, right? But, when i try use the using(){} statement, i get an error about the implementation of the IDisposable interface. If you want i can send you my code.

Comment: @LéoJenkins Your controller should not dispose the repository. So you shouldn't call `Dispose()` or `Dispose(true)`, and you should *not* place the repository inside of a using block. How you can properly dispose of the repository depends upon how you are achieving IOC. Are you using a container like Windsor, Unity, or Autofac? Or are you using a factory or service locator? If you could post the code that calls `new Repository()`, that will be helpful.

Comment: @KeithPayne, i'm not using IoC, yet. I'm just calling the repository from the controller. Ill refactor my code to use IoC in the future, but not now. Example of my controller: private IGenericRepository<Profile> _repository; private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new DatabaseContext(); public ProfileController()
{ this._repository = new GenericRepository<Profile>(_unitOfWork); }

Comment: Ahh. I see where this is confusing because I assumed that you were injecting or locating the repository already. One more question - does the repository do anything more than dispose of the `DatabaseContext` in its `Dispose`?

Comment: I'll implements DI in the future, but not know cause I'm learning. My repository does CRUD operations and just dispose de DatabaseContext like you said. Thank you for help me, i'm really grateful.

Comment: See the updated answer. If you implement your own Dispose method, you should always suppress finalization. Finalization has a big effect on GC performance. @HighCore

Comment: Thank you! @KeithPayne. One more thing, why you said that my class may not need to be disposed?

Comment: This code: `IDisposable d = _repository as IDisposable;` Its not the same thing that public interface `IGenericRepository<T> : where T : class, IDisposable`???

Comment: You should not inherit `IDisposable` in the interface. When you make this work with an IOC container, `IDisposable` on the interface will be useless. It will be mostly useless in your temporary code now, in fact. It is saving you exactly two lines of code that you will delete soon anyways.
`IDisposable` is an implementation detail of `GenericRepository` and not part of the functional abstraction `IGenericRepository<T>`. I'm not sure how to express this another way.

Comment: Edit your question and include the following source code and I'll re-write it to express what I am talking about: IUnitOfWork, DatabaseContext, IGenericRepository<T>, GenericRepository<T>, ProfileController. Also, add a comment so that I see it in my inbox.

Comment: @KeithPayne, good morning! I edited my question as you asked. :)

Answer (score 4):

Have your `Interface` inherit from `IDisposable`:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
   //...
}
```

Class:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Comment: I was putting a comma after IDisposable, thank you, really, you save me!

Comment: I disagree with this answer. The "disposability" of an `IGenericRepository` object is an implementation detail and does not belong in the interface but on the class declaration. The repository pattern is meant to hide the implementation details, such as the state of a `DbConnection`, from the consumer. By making the interface `IDisposable`, the consumer must now take the responsibility for the private concerns of the class.

Comment: @KeithPayne that's what the OP is looking for. And yes this is awesome because then you may resolve the repository via DI or Service Locator and use `using` statement on it, without having to cast to IDisposable. And it is not a matter of "private concerns of the class", because the very class itself is disposable, not a private member or something.

Comment: @HighCore The class is disposable, not all implementations of the interface are disposable. An in-memory repository would not generally need to be disposable, for instance. If one wants to avoid casting to `IDisposable` at all costs, an `IDisposableGenericRepository<T>` interface could be used.

Comment: @KeithPayne in my case, all implementations of the interface were disposable. Yes, maybe that's a more proper name for this.

Comment: @KeithPayne, the implementation of the dispose method is being made in the repository class, but, in my controller i refer to the interface, not to the class, like this `IRepo test` and `test = re repo()`. With this, if i want to access the dispose method in a public scope, i need inherit the IDisposable in the interface, because if i put the inheritance in the class, the dispose method will be hidden for my controller.

Comment: Are you constructing the repository object within the controller?

Comment: No, a controller of my MVC Application will consume my repository. My controller expects a interface of the repository as a param. Example: `private IRepository _repository;` and `this._repository = new AnyRepository();` instead of `private AnyRepository _repository;` and `this._repository = new AnyRepository();`. So, when i type the command `this._repository.[intellisense list]`, the intellisense lists the properties and methods of the interface, instead of properties and methods of the class.

Comment: @HighCore See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Single Resposibility Principle**

- If you look at SRP and use that in MVC it tells you that when you have transactions that are made up of multiple methods (`CRUDS`) thats not a correct way of implementing the transactions.
- So you should put those multiple (`CRUD`) methods in one method and in that `Transaction` method implement `using` for the `database context` so you can pass that `database context` to those called `private` methods that make up the transaction method. If all those (`CRUD`) methods succeed you can call the `Commit` method (`SaveChanges`). When those methods fail you do nothing (=`Rollback`). So make sure no `Commit` is executed in those methods but delegate it to the Transaction method.
- By implementing the 2nd bullet `IDispose` is not needed in Repositories because `using` takes care of cleaning up the `database context`.
- If `Connection Pooling` is used thats an efficient way of implementing it and it will be scalable.

In the way you setup a Class above it feels wrong. Because in the constructor for the Repository you could set the `database context` and use that same `context`in several methods but then you would need to implement `IDispose` because you need to cleanup the connections yourself. In lots of examples for Repositories its implemented this way buts from a SRP point of view thats not right and should be changed according to the 2nd bullet above.

Answer (score 0):

**Context:** You asked for the correct way to implement the dispose functionality.

**Solution:** This is an alternative for this and any other cases. this automatic alternative is suggested by Visual Studio itself (I tested in VS2017 and VS2019) :

1. Add the IDisposable contract next to your class name => class MyClass : IDisposable
2. Then with cursor still on that word "IDisposable", do Alt+Enter or Ctrl+. to enable "Quick Actions"
3. Then select "Implement interface with Dispose pattern"
4. Finally you can complete that code-pattern for your managed and unmanaged objects following suggestions indicated in comments.