# Is warning CA1001 implement IDisposable negligible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, idisposable

I am using `Repository` pattern and having my general repository class

```
public class GeneralRepository<T> where T:class
{
    private Context con = new Context();
    protected DbSet<T> Dbset { get; set; }

    public GeneralRepository()
    {
        Dbset = con.Set<T>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return Dbset;
    }
    public T SelectByID(int? id)
    {
        var rec = Dbset.Find(id);
        return rec;
    }
    public void AddRecord(T entity)
    {
        Dbset.Add(entity);
    }
    public void EditRecord(T entity)
    {
        con.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Detach(T entity)
    {
       con.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        con.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

There are multiple native repositories which are inheriting my General repository like:

```
public class EmailAssignRepository:GeneralRepository<EmailAssign>
public class DepartmentRepository:GeneralRepository<Department>
```

Everything is running fine in my code , but it gave me warning when I run code analysis. What does it mean? is it negligible? If not how to overcome this warning?

Comment: No, don't ignore. Make the Repository IDisposable or, better, get rid of `= new Context();`. Look into Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1001-types-that-own-disposable-fields-should-be-disposable?view=vs-2015#code-snippet-1):

> A class implements the `IDisposable` interface to dispose of unmanaged
>   resources that it owns. An instance field that is an `IDisposable` type
>   indicates that the field owns an unmanaged resource. A class that
>   declares an `IDisposable` field indirectly owns an unmanaged resource
>   and should implement the `IDisposable` interface. If the class does not
>   directly own any unmanaged resources, it should not implement a
>   finalizer.

Cause:

> A class declares and implements an instance field that is a
>   `System.IDisposable` type and the class does not implement `IDisposable`.

How to Fix Violations

> To fix a violation of this rule, implement `IDisposable` and from the
>   `System.IDisposable.Dispose` method call the `Dispose` method of the
>   field.

And see this: [How to implement IDisposable inheritance in a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358844/how-to-implement-idisposable-inheritance-in-a-repository)

---

When to Suppress Warnings (and your question *is it negligible ?* No)

> Do not suppress a warning from this rule.

Comment: should i implement it on general rep and call that dispose method  after each query in my controller?

Comment: @Replynot Have a look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358844/how-to-implement-idisposable-inheritance-in-a-repository

Comment: Got it , Thanks for the efforts